# Which memo program is recommended

Tags: memo

I'm seeing `MemoSq4gqABAXKb96qnH8TysNcWxMyWCqXgDLGmfcHr` referenced in [solana cookbook](https://solanacookbook.com/references/basic-transactions.html#getfeeformessage) and [memo doc](https://spl.solana.com/memo) but also seeing another memo program `Memo1UhkJRfHyvLMcVucJwxXeuD728EqVDDwQDxFMNo` used by others e.g Magic Eden. What are their differences and which one is recommended?

Comment: I'm guessing one is v1 and the other v2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Memo1UhkJRfHyvLMcVucJwxXeuD728EqVDDwQDxFMNo` is for v1 of the memo program.

`MemoSq4gqABAXKb96qnH8TysNcWxMyWCqXgDLGmfcHr` is for the latest memo program.

You can see that in the source code for the [memo program](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/memo/program/src/lib.rs#L16)